# How can I bypass IIS 10.xx error handling and let Application_Error take care of all error/exception handling?

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms

I have inherited an Asp.NET webforms application and I am getting a lot of errors like "HTTP Error 404.13 - Not Found" thrown by IIS. I do have error handling code in Global.asax. I tried adding 
in  but nothing seems to work. I want to show custom error pages from Application_Error.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can config Error page or url  in IIS setting. Asp.net error handling  just hanlding aplication's error.But `HTTP Error 404.13 - Not Found` is the http error.